# Will OpenGL legacy functions work together with GLSL in one program?

Tags: opengl

I am trying to extend a program that uses OpenGL legacy functions, for example, `glOrtho`, but I want to use GLSL. Can I simply add the new feature using GLSL and work together with the old functions? Or do I have to reconstruct all of them into part of the GLSL shader? If I do have to reconstruct it, are there any cheat sheet that help translate it? And if I am only tend to modify the fragment shader, do I have to reconstruct the functions involving vertex shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to an OpenGL implementation that implements fixed-functionality, and you attempt to use shaders, the shaders will *replace* that fixed functionality. This is standard, going back to the older assembly shader extensions (ARB_vertex_program and the like).

Using a vertex shader turns off *all* fixed function vertex processing. Using a fragment shader turns off all fixed-function fragment processing.

That being said, it is replacing *processing*. That's different from *state*. For example:

> I think functions like glOrtho is actually writing a vertex shader

You are wrong. `glOrtho` only multiplies the current matrix by another one. It doesn't actually do any vertex processing; it simply sets state which is *used* by vertex processing.

Compatibility GLSL has a number of built-in variables for accessing fixed-function state. For example, `gl_ProjectionMatrix` is the value of the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix. So if you apply `glOrtho` while that matrix is current, any shaders can choose to read that matrix through that variable.

Having a vertex shader will prevent any rendering operation from using the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix in accord with fixed-function processing. But your vertex shader can *choose* to use `GL_PROJECTION` to do its own processing. So while a shader overrides fixed-function *processing*, it doesn't override fixed-function *state*.

Shaders can access a lot of state through these compatibility variables. But they can't access all rendering state. Light parameters, material parameters, fog parameters, all kinds of stuff. But what shaders can't (generally) access are most `glEnable/Disable` switches. The idea being that whether or not you're using certain state is what the *shader* does; it's a property of the shader itself.

Now, while a lot of per-vertex state is accessible from a shader, not a lot of per-fragment state is. The fog parameters are, but not texture environment settings. Even texture bindings have to be treated as user-defined samplers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any list of all the fixed functions that will be disabled after using a shader, and their corresponding compatibility variables?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can use legacy OpenGL stuff by creating a compatibility context. Take a look at the OpenGL documentation [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts). Although if your only intention is to use legacy math library with functions like `glOrtho()`, it is not worth it. You should probably write your own or use 3rd-parties, like [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/index.html).

Comment: I don't mean loading legacy functions on a new platform. I think functions like `glOrtho` is actually writing a vertex shader and functions like `glAlpha` is actually writing a fragment shader. If I implement a new shader, will they still work?

Comment: @RoastDuck What do you mean by "`glOrtho` is writing a vertex shader"? Also, these functions doesn't exist if you use OpenGL 3.1+.